# Play Store can't update apps

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, xiaomi, miui

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 5A with mi-globe MIUI 11 ROM, with Magisk 20.0 root. Yesterday, Play Store updates suddenly stopped working. I checked the logcat and it appears it's trying to link `/data/app/com.google.android.apps.photos-Q_Pb6hixcLrelRKL6ammsw==//oat/arm64/base.odex` to `/data/app/vmdl1427524294.tmp//oat/arm64/base.odex`. The "`//`" directory does not exist of course, but I don't know why is it trying to link. Here is the full logcat:

```
10-27 15:49:49.350   761  2417 E installd: Failed to link from /data/app/com.google.android.apps.photos-Q_Pb6hixcLrelRKL6ammsw==//oat/arm64/base.odex to /data/app/vmdl1427524294.tmp//oat/arm64/base.odex: No such file or directory
10-27 15:49:49.354  1552  1619 E PackageInstaller: Commit of session 1427524294 failed: Failed to inherit existing install: failed linkOrCreateDir(/oat/arm64/base.odex, /data/app/com.google.android.apps.photos-Q_Pb6hixcLrelRKL6ammsw==, /data/app/vmdl1427524294.tmp): android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Failed to link from /data/app/com.google.android.apps.photos-Q_Pb6hixcLrelRKL6ammsw==//oat/arm64/base.odex to /data/app/vmdl1427524294.tmp//oat/arm64/base.odex (code 2)
10-27 15:49:49.360   761  2417 E         : Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1427524294.tmp: No such file or directory
10-27 15:49:49.360   761  2417 E installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1427524294.tmp: No such file or directory
10-27 15:49:49.365  3533  3533 E Finsky  : [2] qgv.onReceive(19): Error -506 while installing com.google.android.apps.photos: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE: Failed to inherit existing install: failed linkOrCreateDir(/oat/arm64/base.odex, /data/app/com.google.android.apps.photos-Q_Pb6hixcLrelRKL6ammsw==, /data/app/vmdl1427524294.tmp): android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Failed to link from /data/app/com.google.android.apps.photos-Q_Pb6hixcLrelRKL6ammsw==//oat/arm64/base.odex to /data/app/vmdl1427524294.tmp//oat/arm64/base.odex (code 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Backing up the apps' data in `data/data` then uninstalling and reinstalling them solved my problem, also the next updates worked, but can you help me figuring out why did this happen?